# force all sockets to close in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

How can I force all currently open sockets in linux to close from the command line?

Comment: This is hard, I think it would be easier to answer if you said why.  All of your sockets?  All on the computer?  Kill apps or not?

Comment: If you do that, the programs using these sockets will encounter errors, which they might or might not handle. Is that what you want?

Comment: Maybe you could describe *why* you want to do this. Then it'll be easier to help. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to shut down a specific interface, for example:

```
# ifconfig eth0 down
```

Answer (score 0):

to flush all your rules in the filter table
iptables -F
set default behavior to drop in INPUT chain
iptables -P INPUT DROP

at this point all local sockets should be unavailable to a remote host
if you have a redhat based os you should also use
iptables -X
to get rid of their custom chain for INPUT

if you want to the rules to remain on startup then you need to either include these in a script that runs in the /etc/rc.local file or use iptables save

This is all assuming that what you said you want to do is what you want to do.